# No public page Info from Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to query the graph api for any Fan page I get the info about them such as their ID, Name, About etc. Here's an example:

https://graph.facebook.com/google

However certain pages return no information at all! An example:

http://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/CobaltHeights

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It just means that "CobaltHeights" is not the namespace of any existing page.

#### Adding a namespace to a page

In other words, the page doesn't have its page address (in the page settings -> "page info" tab) configured as `https://www.facebook.com/CobaltHeights`:

[image]

or:

[image: Your page needs at least 25 fans to have a web address.]

#### Calling Graph API for a page without a namespace

If your page URL looks like:

`https://www.facebook.com/pages/CobaltHeights/205123456718603`

Then your page ID will be `205123456718603` and you could call:

https://graph.facebook.com/205123456718603

Comment: But what does that mean? The page clearly exists, and is active.. How would I get information about them?

Comment: Make sure you set a namespace for the page.

Comment: How does one go about this? I wasn't aware pages set namespaces for themselves? This is an ordinary fanpage not a Page App...

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer. If I have no control over the page (ie it isn't mine), is it possible to retrieve the ID like you did there? If so how?
BTW the link returns an error - Unsupported get request.

Comment: All your questions answered here: https://www.facebook.com/help/409473442437047. It returns an error because this URL has been invented... If this isn't your page, just look at the page URL or get the page ID through the Graph API.

Comment: But that's the thing - the Page URL is just that: https://www.facebook.com/CobaltHeights

And Graph API returns nothing for that page... 
This is what I'm seeing on Graph API:
http://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/CobaltHeights

Comment: I don't see any active page on https://www.facebook.com/CobaltHeights. Maybe your page is not published yet?

Comment: No it is, it has 2K+ likes and I can certainly see it... So you're clicking on the link but nothing is showing up for you? Perhaps there are some settings which prevent users from outside a certain country from seeing it?..

Comment: Oh... you are right, that may be a country restriction. Sorry!